# sql repeating question

Tags: sql

Got exactly the same question as i asked before: [sql take one out from the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266418/sql-take-one-out-from-the-list) :) but i cant integrate the

`CPA.WANT_EMAIL = 1`

instead of

`AND CPA.PARTNER_ID = CCD.PARTNER_ID AND CCD.SITE_DOMAIN = 'www.projedepo.com')`

i mean want_email is also from `COMPANY_PARTNER CPA`everything is the same, except, site_domain is needed to be exactly the same as www.projedepo.com but for want_email, i need just the negative, 0 or positive 1, the formats of values are different.

how do i do it? thx for help everyone!

Here is the code for now:

```
<cfquery name="GET_POT_COMPANY" datasource="#DSN#">
    SELECT
        C.COMPANY_ID,
        C.MEMBER_CODE,
        C.FULLNAME,
        C.PARTNER_ID,
        C.RECORD_DATE,
        CC.COMPANYCAT
          <cfif isdefined('attributes.report_sort2')
            and attributes.report_sort2 is 1>
            , 'www.projedepo.com' AS SITE_DOMAIN
          </cfif>
    FROM 
        COMPANY C, 
        COMPANY_CAT CC
    WHERE
          C.COMPANYCAT_ID = #attributes.comp_cat# 
      AND CC.COMPANYCAT_ID = C.COMPANYCAT_ID
        <cfif isdefined('attributes.report_sort2')
          and attributes.report_sort2 is 1>
          AND EXISTS
            ( SELECT *
              FROM
                COMPANY_CONSUMER_DOMAINS CCD,
                COMPANY_PARTNER CPA
              WHERE C.COMPANY_ID = CPA.COMPANY_ID
                AND CPA.PARTNER_ID = CCD.PARTNER_ID
                AND CCD.SITE_DOMAIN = 'www.projedepo.com'
            )
        </cfif>
    ORDER BY 
        C.RECORD_DATE DESC
</cfquery>
```

this is the previous example, the working one, all i need is to change the `AND CPA.PARTNER_ID = CCD.PARTNER_ID AND CCD.SITE_DOMAIN = 'www.projedepo.com'`

to `CPA.WANT_EMAIL = 1`

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are the results? How are the results different from what you need?

Comment: @Leigh the thing is, there are companies, and partners, that are in these companies, for example, i wanted to list just the companies but it lists for example the same company tree times, because there are 3 partners in it, because the definition of want_email = 1 is defined from partners, not from the companies, all i need is to be displayed the company just one time, not tree times. in the previous example, it worked fine, but with definition of who has CCD.SITE_DOMAIN = 'www.projedepo.com' but i cant integrate want_email the same way

Comment: Here's a problem. Those not acquainted with your previous question might not be very interested in jumping to that post to try to get into particulars, then getting back to read the new requirement, then returning to re-read the previous question to see the difference etc. And those who *are* acquainted might temporarily have lost their interest to the same kind of problem. So **please** don't make people collect the full info by pieces. Just present all the important information in one place. (But the link to the previous question is fine, that way people can see it's not a duplicate.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work for you:

```
. . .
      AND EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
          FROM
            COMPANY_PARTNER CPA
          WHERE C.COMPANY_ID = CPA.COMPANY_ID
            AND CPA.WANT_EMAIL = 1
        )
. . .
```

?

That is, just replace the existing EXISTS subquery with this one.

---

**UPDATE**

Looks like a different approach is needed here. Try this:

```
<cfquery name="GET_POT_COMPANY" datasource="#DSN#">
    SELECT
        C.COMPANY_ID,
        C.MEMBER_CODE,
        C.FULLNAME,
        C.PARTNER_ID,
        C.RECORD_DATE,
        CC.COMPANYCAT
          <cfif isdefined('attributes.report_sort2')
            and attributes.report_sort2 is 1>
            , COALESCE(CPA.WANT_EMAIL, 0) AS WANT_EMAIL
          </cfif>
    FROM 
        COMPANY C
        INNER JOIN COMPANY_CAT CC ON CC.COMPANYCAT_ID = C.COMPANYCAT_ID
         <cfif isdefined('attributes.report_sort2')
          and attributes.report_sort2 is 1>
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
                COMPANY_ID,
                MAX(CAST(WANT_EMAIL AS int)) AS WANT_EMAIL
            FROM
                COMPANY_PARTNER CPA
            GROUP BY COMPANY_ID
        ) CPA ON C.COMPANY_ID = CPA.COMPANY_ID
        </cfif>
    WHERE
        C.COMPANYCAT_ID = #attributes.comp_cat# 
    ORDER BY 
        C.RECORD_DATE DESC
</cfquery>
```

Comment: @Andriy M this is maybe ok for "where" part, but what about the "select" part?

Comment: @user775917: *all i need is to change the `AND CPA.PARTNER_ID = CCD.PARTNER_ID AND CCD.SITE_DOMAIN = 'www.projedepo.com'`* – your words. Now it seems like that was not all you needed. Please clarify your request (edit your question). Maybe add a sample of data and the desired output, that often helps much.

Comment: @user775917 - (Edit) Maybe I am misunderstanding, but if you are searching for a *specific* `WANT_EMAIL` value then you already know what to return. ie If you are searching for companies `WHERE want_email = 1`, just return 1. If searching for `want_email = 0`, then return 0. So can you not just derive it the same as you are doing for SITE_DOMAIN? Not necessarily the best approach, but it is consistent with your other query.

Comment: @Andriy M ofcourse i didnt mean it literally, i meant i need to adapt it, the way you replaced them didnt work, it even overloaded the server )) we have to restart it now, as u saw in the previous example, please pay attention, in the select part there is a `<cfif isdefined('attributes.report_sort2')
            and attributes.report_sort2 is 1>
            , 'www.projedepo.com' AS SITE_DOMAIN
          </cfif>` which you didnt change

Comment: @user775917: All right, I updated my answer with a different solution. Please let me know if anything's wrong.

Comment: @Andriy M it reports: Error Executing Database Query. Operand data type bit is invalid for max operator.

Comment: @user775917 - Re: *it even overloaded the server* How? I do not see a problem with the sql suggested earlier. Maybe you used something different ...? Like left in the `COMPANY_CONSUMER_DOMAINS` table and forgot to join on `PARTNER_ID`. I could see how that would create a cartesian product ...

Comment: @Andriy M Андрей :) ты же с Украины? должен знать русский )) помоги пож-та! у тебя есть аська или там мсн или еще что?! @Leigh no the overload was before he updated the answer.

Comment: `Operand data type bit is invalid for max operator` Try casting it to a type that is allowed with `MAX` first. For example `MAX( CAST(TheBitColumn as INT) )`

Comment: @user775917 - Yeah, but the original only had one table in the subquery and the relationship is correct ie `C.COMPANY_ID = CPA.COMPANY_ID`. So it should not cause the issue you described. That is why I think you may have used a different subquery.

Comment: @Leigh: now it reports: Type WANT_EMAIL is not a defined system type.

Comment: @user775917 - Sounds like you dropped the alias maybe? Make sure it looks like this `MAX( CAST(WANT_EMAIL as INT) ) AS WANT_EMAIL`

Comment: @Andriy M and @Leigh ooh jesus! thank you guys! it finally works! :)